# How to do query search on child models while fetching the parent model?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I have the following setup:

1. Job hasMany Quotation
2. Quotation belongsTo Job
3. Quotation hasMany QuotationsInBatch
4. Batch hasMany QuotationsInBatch

I want to do `$this->find` on the following conditions:

- Job.name OR
- Quotation.quotation_number OR
- Quotation.site_text

retrieving the following results:

the various Job records and the Quotations that belongTo the Job and the various Batches that are associated with the Quotation

Meaning to say if I type `abc` and

- a Job.name matches `abc`, I will display that Job and its associated Quotations and associated Batch OR
- a Quotation.quotation_number matches `abc`, I will display the parent Job and all its associated Quotations and associated Batch OR
- a Quotation.site_text matches `abc`, I will display the parent Job and all its associated Quotations and associated Batch

Please advise.

**UPDATE:**

I got this to work. But essentially, I use `find` two times and `joins`

First I do this:

```
     $options =  array(
        'conditions'    => $conditions,
        'order'     => array(
            'Job.id' => 'DESC',
        ),
        'fields'    => $fields
    );

    $joins = array(
        array('table' => 'quotations',
            'alias' => 'Quotation',
            'type' => 'LEFT',
            'conditions' => array(
                'Quotation.job_id = Job.id',
            )
        )
    );
    $options['joins'] = $joins;

    $results = $this->find('all', $options);
```

Because my conditions largely are concerned with `Job` and `Quotation`, I do a search with joins between these two models and only return `Job.id`

After which I check if there are Jobs that match the criteria, and then perform another find. This time, with the other associated Models involved.

```
    if ($results) {
        $ids = Hash::extract($results, '{n}.Job.id');
    } else {
        $ids = array('Job.id' => -1000); // put a fake id
    }

    $options['conditions'] = array('Job.id' => $ids);
    $joins[] = array('table' => 'quotations_in_batches',
            'alias' => 'QuotationInBatch',
            'type' => 'LEFT',
            'conditions' => array(
                'Quotation.id = QuotationInBatch.quotation_id',
            )
        );
    $joins[] = array('table' => 'batches',
            'alias' => 'Batch',
            'type' => 'LEFT',
            'conditions' => array(
                'Batch.id = QuotationInBatch.batch_id',
            )
        );
```

Then perform a `find` using these options.

Is there a better way than mine?

Comment: Checks docs: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#complex-find-conditions